# PUMA ArgumentError: couldn't find login name -- expanding `~'

Tags: ruby, puma

Can't start Puma for some reason. Getting this error

```
ArgumentError: couldn't find login name -- expanding `~'
```

With the below back trace

```
Feb 03 15:44:21 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: Done in 1.33s.
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: rake aborted!
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: ArgumentError: couldn't find login name -- expanding `~'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:5:in `expand_path'     
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:5:in `<class:Pry>'     
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry.rb:119:in `require'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry.rb:119:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'        
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /opt/shopify_shipping_refactor/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /opt/shopify_shipping_refactor/Rakefile:4:in `require'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /opt/shopify_shipping_refactor/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor puma[3061]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor systemd[1]: puma.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor systemd[1]: Failed to start puma.service.
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor systemd[1]: puma.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 03 15:44:25 shopify-shipping-refactor systemd[1]: puma.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 3):

**Analysis:** Ruby's `expand_path` calls into the C-based runtime (obscuring the stack trace), but eventually ends up in [`rb_default_home_dir`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_5/file.c#L3422-L3449) to figure out what `'~'` is. This method relies on the `$HOME` environment variable to figure this out and falls back to `getlogin()` ([getlogin(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin)) and `getpwnam()` if it's not available.

**Cause:** The error message you're seeing is from that fallback failing, since (presumably) your process is not registered with a controlling tty and login user.

**Solution:** Set $HOME when running puma. Use a directory that you want the Puma to use as a home directory when `'~'` is specified.