# Lambda ArgumentError: couldn't find login name -- expanding `~'

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running my Lamda and it fails on `app_developer_status` script below with the following error (see logs below). I am a bit confused and don't have a clear understanding on what I should check now.. I've read a similar post here: [PUMA ArgumentError: couldn't find login name -- expanding `~'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60042591/puma-argumenterror-couldnt-find-login-name-expanding)
but it doesn't really help. I already thought that the problem is in `require` but it shouldn't be this. What is the reason?

#### Logs from Lambda

```
2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   Init error when loading handler src/apple_developer_status/apple_developer_status.run

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   {

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "errorMessage": "couldn't find login name -- expanding `~'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "errorType": "Init<ArgumentError>",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "stackTrace": [

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/config.rb:314:in `expand_path'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/config.rb:314:in `default_rc_file'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/config.rb:187:in `initialize'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:327:in `new'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:327:in `reset_defaults'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:337:in `init'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:388:in `<top (required)>'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:96:in `require'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:96:in `require'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:160:in `require'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:160:in `rescue in require'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/src/apple_developer_status/fetch_apple_developer_status.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/src/apple_developer_status/apple_developer_status.rb:4:in `require_relative'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/task/src/apple_developer_status/apple_developer_status.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'",

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'"

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   ]

2021-04-09T19:46:35.994+03:00   }
```

#### app_developer_status.rb Script

```
require 'json'
require File.join(File.expand_path('.'), "scripts", "build_helper.rb")
require File.join(File.expand_path('.'), "models", "developer_status.rb")
require_relative 'fetch_apple_developer_status'
require 'dynamoid'

def run(event:, context:)
  puts "#{event}"
    puts "#{context}"
  puts "#{event['app_ids']}"
  app_ids = event['app_ids']

  invalid_apps = FetchAppleDeveloperStatus.fetch(app_ids)

  Dynamoid.configure do |config|
    config.access_key = ENV["S3_AWS_ACCESS_KEY"]
    config.secret_key = ENV["S3_AWS_SECRET"]
    config.region = 'us-west-2'
    config.namespace = nil
  end
```